# Can not fetch datetime column when use curor in store procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I use a curor to fetch two values, int and datetime, but I find the return value is null instead of a datetime value.

```
mysql> select * from test1|
+-------+---------------------+ 
| id    | qdtime              |
+-------+---------------------+ 
| 10001 | 2015-03-05 12:15:36 | 
| 10004 | 2015-03-05 12:15:36 |
+-------+---------------------+ 
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter | 
mysql> drop procedure if exists demo | 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create procedure demo()
    -> BEGIN
    ->    DECLARE TARGETID INT;
    ->    DECLARE QDTIME DATETIME;
    ->    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    ->    DECLARE CUR1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,qdtime FROM test1;
    ->    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    ->    OPEN CUR1;
    ->  judge_loop: LOOP
    ->    FETCH CUR1 INTO TARGETID, QDTIME;
    ->    IF done THEN
    ->      LEAVE judge_loop;
    ->    END IF;
    ->
    ->    SELECT TARGETID, QDTIME;
    -> END LOOP;
    -> CLOSE CUR1;
    -> END;| Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> call demo()|
+----------+--------+ 
| TARGETID | QDTIME |
+----------+--------+ 
|    10001 | NULL   |
+----------+--------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----------+--------+ 
| TARGETID | QDTIME |
+----------+--------+ 
|    10004 | NULL   |
+----------+--------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never name a variable like columns or anything. To avoid unclear names use prefixes. For example, let every variable start with `v_` and every parameter with `p_`. This also greatly improves code readability.

Your cursor

```
DECLARE CUR1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,qdtime FROM test1;
```

selects here the variable, not the column. Since your variable has the value `NULL` at this moment, so has your result.